# @SceneStorage on iPad potrait doesn't show the correct screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Overview

- On the iPad Portrait mode using `@SceneStorage` doesn't show the detail screen, instead it shows the place holder screen.
- Tapping on the back button then shows the restored detail screen

## Problem

`@SceneStorage` **successfully restores** the value, however the problem is about the **navigation stack after the value is restored**.

## Steps to Reproduce

1. Run on iPad potrait
2. Select the Car "bbb"
3. See the Car Detail with the car name "bbb"
4. Enter background
5. Repeat steps 1 and 2

## Actual Behaviour:

Notice the car name is not displayed, it shows the "No car selected" text, tapping on the back button then shows the CarDetail screen with the name "bbb"

## Expected Behaviour:

The shows the CarDetail screen should show with the name "bbb" immediately instead of showing the place holder screen

## Note:

- It works fine on iPhone potrait and iPad landscape
- Problem is on iPad potrait and iPhone 13 Pro max landscape

## GIF

[image: Screen recording of the problem]

## Configuration

- iPad OS 15.5
- Xcode 13.4 (13F17a)
- macOS 12.4 (21F79)

## Code:

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            CarList()
            Text("No car selected")
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

**CarList**

```
struct CarList: View {
    
    let cars = [Car(id: 1, name: "aaa"),
                Car(id: 2, name: "bbb"),
                Car(id: 3, name: "ccc")]
    
    @SceneStorage("selectedCarID") private var selectedCarID: Int?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(cars) { car in
                NavigationLink(tag: car.id, selection: $selectedCarID) {
                    CarDetail(name: car.name)
                } label: {
                    Text(car.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**CarDetail**

```
struct CarDetail: View {
    let name: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.brown
            Text(name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
        }
    }
}
```

**Car**

```
struct Car: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.4 / iPadOS 15.5. Note, if you re-run at step 5 from Xcode then it is incorrect, because Xcode *destroys* previous app instance, in user scenario app is activated by tap on app icon on a device, ie. activating same run-time.

Comment: Don't leave the app running in the background. Close the app completely, re-open the app by tapping on the icon and you will notice that this issue exists

Comment: can reproduce the problem. Didn't find a cure. If you use `.navigationViewStyle(.stack)` it works, but I suppose that is not what you want.

Comment: Yeah sadly that is not what I want. I have filed a bug. Hoping it gets fixed

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with `@SceneStorage`. Unfortunately this is just how SwiftUI works at the moment with this navigation style.

Answer (score 0):

I faced such issue on iPhone 13 pro max in landscape position, it uses iPad behavior. Add .navigationViewStyle(.stack) for NavigationView for change behaviour.

NavigationView {

//content

}`.navigationViewStyle(.stack)`

Comment: After adding I had the correct behavior for @SceneStorage

Comment: Yeah sadly that is not what I want. I would like to use the split view on an iPad as shown above. I have filed a bug. Hope it gets fixed

Answer (score -1):

The official docs on [SceneStorage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenestorage) -

> The system manages the saving and restoring of SceneStorage on your behalf. The underlying data that backs SceneStorage is not available to you, so you must access it via the SceneStorage property wrapper. The system makes no guarantees as to when and how often the data will be persisted.
>
> Each Scene has its own notion of SceneStorage, so data is not shared
> between scenes.
>
> Ensure that the data you use with SceneStorage is lightweight. Data of
> a large size, such as model data, should not be stored in
> SceneStorage, as poor performance may result.
>
> If the Scene is explicitly destroyed (e.g. the switcher snapshot is
> destroyed on iPadOS or the window is closed on macOS), the data is
> also destroyed. Do not use SceneStorage with sensitive data.

I reproduced as you mentioned in the steps and saw the same behaviour.

Also if you noticed switching the emulator back to portrait in iPhone 13 pro max and landscape in iPad Pro (12.9-inch) poof MAGIC the Car detail screens comes back automatically.

So, I guess it's a bug on apple's side where SceneStorage is not working in certain orientation of some devices. Should let them know to fix it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `@SceneStorage`, value restores the value successfully. Problem is what happens after value is restored, the navigation stack seems to be wrong.

Comment: Still it gives the expected behaviour when the emulators are rotated. You can check it, so that seems to be a bug that simply rotating screen changes the navigation stack.